# build many versions of user with a resource on rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

Im having issues creating notifications. Notification gems only works peffectly fine with creating notification  at comment creation and updates. what about posts creation and update. thats the issue. I have a model mycase that has comments and tasks.
the notification works well on the comments and tasks but on creation and update of mycase it does not. I have to build the diff versions of users several times but its not realizable. I dont know how to get this done on rails. I have admin, adminassistance, attorny_user and client all from the same model and class User.
I am using activity_notification gem.
this my user.rb

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
belongs_to :lawfirm
has_many :mycases
has_many :tasks
has_many :mycasecomments
has_many :posts
has_many :comments
acts_as_target
rolify

devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
end
```

here is my  mycase.rb

```
class Mycase < ApplicationRecord
enum status: [:open, :under_review, :pending, :completed, :closed]
has_many :mycasecomments, dependent: :destroy
has_many :tasks, dependent: :destroy
belongs_to :lawfirm
belongs_to :attorney_user, class_name: 'User', foreign_key:     :attorney_user_id, optional: true
belongs_to :client, class_name: 'User',foreign_key: :client_id, optional: true    


belongs_to :admin,  class_name: 'User',foreign_key: :admin_id,optional: true, optional: true
belongs_to :adminassistance, class_name: 'User',foreign_key: :adminassistance_id, optional: true
attr_readonly :caseNo


has_many :mycasecommented_users, through: :mycasecomments, source: :user
has_many :tasked_users, through: :tasks, source: :user

acts_as_notifiable :users,
#Notification targets as :targets
# Set to notify to author and users commented to the article, except    comment owner self
targets: ->(mycase, key) {
  ([mycase.attorney_user] + [mycase.client]+[mycase.admin] +[mycase.adminassistance]).uniq
},
# Path to move when the notification is opened by the target user
# This is an optional configuration since activity_notification uses polymorphic_path as default
#tracked: true,
notifiable_path: :mycase_notifiable_path

def mycase_notifiable_path
  mycase_path(self.id)
end


def start_time
    self.arrival_date ##Where 'start' is a attribute of type 'Date' accessible through MyModel's relationship
end

def end_time
    self.due_date ##Where 'start' is a attribute of type 'Date' accessible through MyModel's relationship
end

end
```

here is mycases_controllers

```
class MycasesController < ApplicationController
load_and_authorize_resource :mycase

skip_before_action :authenticate_user!, :only => [:index, :show]
before_action :set_mycase, only: [:casetask, :meet, :show, :edit, :update, :destroy]


.......  

def create
  @users = User.all
    @users.each do |user| 
    if  user.has_role? :adminassistance, current_user.lawfirm  
        @adminassistance_id = user.id
        @adminassistance = user
        #@adminassistance = user
        #user.mycases.build(mycase_params)
    elsif user.has_role? :lawfirmadmin, current_user.lawfirm   
       @admin_id = user.id
       @admin = user
       #@admin = user
      #user.mycases.build(mycase_params)
    end
  end
    #@mycase.lawfirm_id = current_user.lawfirm_id
     @attorney_user = User.find_by(params[@mycase.attorney_user_id])

    @client = User.find_by(params[@mycase.client_id])

    @mycase.admin_id = @admin_id
    @mycase.adminassistance_id  = @adminassistance_id

    @mycase.status= 0
    @mycase = @admin.mycases.build(mycase_params)
    @mycase = @adminassistance.mycases.build(mycase_params)
    @mycase = @client.mycases.build(mycase_params)

    @mycase= @attorney_user.mycases.build(mycase_params)
    @lawfirm = current_user.lawfirm
    @mycase.lawfirm_id=  @lawfirm.id

    @mycase= @lawfirm.mycases.create(mycase_params)
    @mycase.notify :users, key: "Legal Case Created, you are associated"



     respond_to do |format|
        if @mycase.save
        format.html { redirect_to @mycase, notice: 'Legal Case was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @mycase }
        else

        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @mycase.errors, status:            :unprocessable_entity }

      end
      end

      end






    def mycase_params

      params.require(:mycase).permit(:caseNo, :client_name, :subject,      :area_of_practice, :opponents, :assigned_attorney, :arrival_date, :due_date, :status, :summary_of_brief, :add_judge, :add_court, :client_id, :lawfirm_id, :attorney_user_id, :admin_id, :adminassistance_id)
   end
   end
```

Iam having unknown attribute 'user_id' for Mycase.

Please How do I build this so I can get the users through mycase.users, or mycase.admin and so on...????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 acts_as_notifiable :users,
#Notification targets as :targets
# Set to notify to author and users commented to the article, except comment owner self
targets: ->(mycase, key) {
  ([mycase.attorney_user] + [mycase.user]+[mycase.client]).uniq
},
```

I added user_id to mycase and  first of all associated it with a user_id first and all other typed_user asociated properly and notifications get sent to them as well.